# C to Delphi conversion of union and struct with bitfields

Tags: c, delphi

can somebody explain how to convert

```
typedef struct _X86_SELECTOR
{
union
    {
    struct
        {
        WORD wValue;            // packed value
        WORD wReserved;
        };
    struct
        {
        unsigned RPL      :  2; // requested privilege level
        unsigned TI       :  1; // table indicator: 0=gdt, 1=ldt
        unsigned Index    : 13; // index into descriptor table
        unsigned Reserved : 16;
        };
    };
}
X86_SELECTOR, *PX86_SELECTOR, **PPX86_SELECTOR;

#define X86_SELECTOR_ sizeof (X86_SELECTOR)

// -----------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct _X86_DESCRIPTOR
{
union
    {
    struct
        {
        DWORD dValueLow;        // packed value
        DWORD dValueHigh;
        };
    struct
        {
        unsigned Limit1   : 16; // bits 15..00
        unsigned Base1    : 16; // bits 15..00
        unsigned Base2    :  8; // bits 23..16
        unsigned Type     :  4; // segment type
        unsigned S        :  1; // type (0=system, 1=code/data)
        unsigned DPL      :  2; // descriptor privilege level
        unsigned P        :  1; // segment present
        unsigned Limit2   :  4; // bits 19..16
        unsigned AVL      :  1; // available to programmer 
        unsigned Reserved :  1;
        unsigned DB       :  1; // 0=16-bit, 1=32-bit
        unsigned G        :  1; // granularity (1=4KB)
        unsigned Base3    :  8; // bits 31..24
        };
    };
}
X86_DESCRIPTOR, *PX86_DESCRIPTOR, **PPX86_DESCRIPTOR;
```

Comment: Pascal doesn't have bitfields. You'll need to write code to pick out the individual bits. Do you know what bitfields are?

Comment: You've got to format that better.  Plus a little more description of what's going on might be helpful.

Comment: You are also cross-posting: https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=70624

Comment: That is from Undocumented Windows 2000 book. "X86_SELECTOR represents a 16-bit segment selector, as stored in the segment registers CS, DS, ES, FS, GS, and SS."

Comment: X86_SELECTOR structure is a union of two structures. The first one specifies the selector value as a packed 16-bit WORD named wValue, and the second breaks it up into bit-fields. The RPL field specifies the Requested Privilege Level, which is either 0 (kernel-mode) or
3 (user-mode) on Windows 2000. The TI bit switches between the Global and Local Descriptor Tables (GDT/LDT).

Comment: "You are also cross-posting" - yes.

Comment: Are you using 16 bit delphi 1?

Comment: This article shows you how: http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/2008/05/01/working-with-bitfields-in-delphi/  but you also need to do a websearch to learn about C bitfields

Comment: @David, "cross-posting" refers to posting the same question in multiple topics in the same forums (eg., "NativeAPI" and "RTL"). Since SO and EMBT forums (fora?) are separate domains and have no relationship between them, I don't think the term (or criticism) applies here. :)

Comment: SO  isn't a code-writing or consulting service. If you want to make an effort to do it yourself and post what you've tried, we can try to help you figure out what's wrong. You do need to put some effort into it yourself first; David's link to the JEDI blog post shows you where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct translation because Delphi does not support bit fields like C does. The closest transaction would be something like the following:

```
type
  X86_SELECTOR = record
    case Integer of
      0: (
        wValue: WORD; // packed value
        wReserved: WORD);
      1: (
        BitValues: DWORD);
  end;
  PX86_SELECTOR = ^X86_SELECTOR;
  PPX86_SELECTOR = ^PX86_SELECTOR;

const
  X86_SELECTOR_ = SizeOf(X86_SELECTOR);

type
  X86_DESCRIPTOR = record
    case Integer of
      0: (
        dValueLow: DWORD; // packed value
        dValueHigh: DWORD);
      1: (
        BitFields1: DWORD;
        BitFields2: DWORD);
  end;
  PX86_DESCRIPTOR = ^X86_DESCRIPTOR;
  PPX86_DESCRIPTOR = ^PX86_DESCRIPTOR;

function X86_SELECTOR_Get_RPL(const Selector: X86_SELECTOR): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Selector.BitValues and $C0000000) shr 30);
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR_Set_RPL(var Selector: X86_SELECTOR; Value: Byte);
begin
  Selector.BitValues := (Selector.BitValues and $3FFFFFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $03) shl 30);
end;

function X86_SELECTOR_Get_TI(const Selector: X86_SELECTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Selector.BitValues and $20000000) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR_Set_TI(var Selector: X86_SELECTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Selector.BitValues := (Selector.BitValues and $DFFFFFFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 29);
end;

function X86_SELECTOR_Get_Index(const Selector: X86_SELECTOR): WORD;
begin
  Result := Word((Selector.BitValues and $1FFF0000) shr 16);
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR_Set_Index(var Selector: X86_SELECTOR; Value: WORD);
begin
  Selector.BitValues := (Selector.BitValues and $E000FFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $1FFF) shl 16);
end;

function X86_SELECTOR_Get_Reserved(const Selector: X86_SELECTOR): Word;
begin
  Result := Word(Selector.BitValues and $FFFF);
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR_Set_Reserved(var Selector: X86_SELECTOR; Value: Word);
begin
  Selector.BitValues := (Selector.BitValues and $FFFF0000) or DWORD(Value);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Limit1(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Word;
begin
  Result := Word(Descriptor.BitFields1 and $FFFF0000) shr 16);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Limit1(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Word);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields1 := (Descriptor.BitFields1 and $0000FFFF) or (DWORD(Value) shl 16);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Base1(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Word;
begin
  Result := Word(Descriptor.BitFields1 and $0000FFFF);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Base1(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Word);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields1 := (Descriptor.BitFields1 and $FFFF0000) or DWORD(Value);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Base2(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FF000000) shr 24);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Base2(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Byte);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00FFFFFF) or (DWORD(Value) shl 24);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Type(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00F00000) shr 20);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Type(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Byte);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FF0FFFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $0F) shl 20);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_S(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00080000) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_S(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFF7FFFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 19);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_DPL(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00060000) shr 17);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_DPL(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Byte);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFF9FFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $03) shl 17);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_P(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00010000) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_P(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFFEFFFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 16);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Limit2(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Descriptor.BitFields2 and $0000F000) shr 12);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Limit2(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Byte);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFF9FFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $0F) shl 12);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_AVL(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00000800) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_AVL(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFFFF7FF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 11);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Reserved(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00000400) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Reserved(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFFFFBFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 10);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_DB(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00000200) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_DB(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFFFFDFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 9);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_G(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $00000100) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_G(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Boolean);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFFFFEFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 8);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR_Get_Base3(const Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR): Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte(Descriptor.BitFields2 and $000000FF);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR_Set_Base3(var Descriptor: X86_DESCRIPTOR; Value: Byte);
begin
  Descriptor.BitFields2 := (Descriptor.BitFields2 and $FFFFFF00) or DWORD(Value);
end;
```

If you are using a modern version of Delphi that supports properties on records, you can do the following instead:

```
type
  X86_SELECTOR = record
  private
    function Get_RPL: Byte;
    procedure Set_RPL(Value: Byte);
    function Get_TI: Boolean;
    procedure Set_TI(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_Index: WORD;
    procedure Set_Index(Value: WORD);
    function Get_Reserved: Word;
    procedure Set_Reserved(Value: Word);
  public
    property RPL: Byte read Get_RPL write Set_RPL;
    property TI: boolean read Get_TI write Set_TI;
    property Index: Word read Get_Index write Set_Index;
    property Reserved: Word read Get_Reserved write Set_Reserved;

    case Integer of
      0: (
        wValue: WORD; // packed value
        wReserved: WORD);
      1: (
        BitValues: DWORD);
  end;
  PX86_SELECTOR = ^X86_SELECTOR;
  PPX86_SELECTOR = ^PX86_SELECTOR;

const
  X86_SELECTOR_ = SizeOf(X86_SELECTOR);

type
  X86_DESCRIPTOR = record
  private
    function Get_Limit1: Word;
    procedure Set_Limit1(Value: Word);
    function Get_Base1: Word;
    procedure Set_Base1(Value: Word);
    function Get_Base2: Byte;
    procedure Set_Base2(Value: Byte);
    function Get_Type: Byte;
    procedure Set_Type(Value: Byte);
    function Get_S: Boolean;
    procedure Set_S(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_DPL: Byte;
    procedure Set_DPL(Value: Byte);
    function Get_P: Boolean;
    procedure Set_P(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_Limit2: Byte;
    procedure Set_Limit2(Value: Byte);
    function Get_AVL: Boolean;
    procedure Set_AVL(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_Reserved: Boolean;
    procedure Set_Reserved(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_DB: Boolean;
    procedure Set_DB(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_G: Boolean;
    procedure Set_G(Value: Boolean);
    function Get_Base3: Byte;
    procedure Set_Base3(Value: Byte);
  public
    property Limit1: Word read Get_Limit1 write Set_Limit1;
    property Base1: Word read Get_Base1 write Set_Base1;
    property Base2: Byte read Get_Base2 write Set_Base2;
    property Type: Byte read Get_Type write Set_Type;
    property S: Boolean read Get_S write Set_S;
    property DPL: Byte read Get_DPL write Set_DPL;
    property P: Boolean read Get_P write Set_P;
    property Limit2: Byte read Get_Limit2 write Set_Limit2;
    property AVL: Boolean read Get_AVL write Set_AVL;
    property Reserved: Boolean read Get_Reserved write Set_Reserved;
    property DB: Boolean read Get_DB write Set_DB;
    property G: Boolean read Get_G write Set_G;
    property Base3: Byte read Get_Base3 write Set_Base3;

    case Integer of
      0: (
        dValueLow: DWORD; // packed value
        dValueHigh: DWORD);
      1: (
        BitFields1: DWORD;
        BitFields2: DWORD);
  end;
  PX86_DESCRIPTOR = ^X86_DESCRIPTOR;
  PPX86_DESCRIPTOR = ^PX86_DESCRIPTOR;

function X86_SELECTOR.Get_RPL: Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Self.BitValues and $C0000000) shr 30);
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR.Set_RPL(Value: Byte);
begin
  Self.BitValues := (Self.BitValues and $3FFFFFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $03) shl 30);
end;

function X86_SELECTOR.Get_TI: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitValues and $20000000) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR.Set_TI(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitValues := (Self.BitValues and $DFFFFFFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 29);
end;

function X86_SELECTOR.Get_Index: WORD;
begin
  Result := Word((Self.BitValues and $1FFF0000) shr 16);
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR.Set_Index(Value: WORD);
begin
  Self.BitValues := (Self.BitValues and $E000FFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $1FFF) shl 16);
end;

function X86_SELECTOR.Get_Reserved: Word;
begin
  Result := Word(Self.BitValues and $FFFF);
end;

procedure X86_SELECTOR.Set_Reserved(Value: Word);
begin
  Self.BitValues := (Self.BitValues and $FFFF0000) or DWORD(Value);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Limit1: Word;
begin
  Result := Word(Self.BitFields1 and $FFFF0000) shr 16);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Limit1(Value: Word);
begin
  Self.BitFields1 := (Self.BitFields1 and $0000FFFF) or (DWORD(Value) shl 16);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Base1: Word;
begin
  Result := Word(Self.BitFields1 and $0000FFFF);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Base1(Value: Word);
begin
  Self.BitFields1 := (Self.BitFields1 and $FFFF0000) or DWORD(Value);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Base2: Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Self.BitFields2 and $FF000000) shr 24);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Base2(Value: Byte);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $00FFFFFF) or (DWORD(Value) shl 24);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Type: Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Self.BitFields2 and $00F00000) shr 20);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Type(Value: Byte);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FF0FFFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $0F) shl 20);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_S: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitFields2 and $00080000) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_S(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFF7FFFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 19);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_DPL: Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Self.BitFields2 and $00060000) shr 17);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_DPL(Value: Byte);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFF9FFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $03) shl 17);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_P: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitFields2 and $00010000) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_P(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFFEFFFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 16);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Limit2: Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte((Self.BitFields2 and $0000F000) shr 12);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Limit2(Value: Byte);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFF9FFFF) or (DWORD(Value and $0F) shl 12);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_AVL: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitFields2 and $00000800) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_AVL(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFFFF7FF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 11);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Reserved: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitFields2 and $00000400) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Reserved(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFFFFBFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 10);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_DB: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitFields2 and $00000200) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_DB(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFFFFDFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 9);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_G: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Self.BitFields2 and $00000100) <> 0;
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_G(Value: Boolean);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFFFFEFF) or (DWORD(Ord(Value)) shl 8);
end;

function X86_DESCRIPTOR.Get_Base3: Byte;
begin
  Result := Byte(Self.BitFields2 and $000000FF);
end;

procedure X86_DESCRIPTOR.Set_Base3(Value: Byte);
begin
  Self.BitFields2 := (Self.BitFields2 and $FFFFFF00) or DWORD(Value);
end;
```